# What do you call a road that goes up and down?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

How does one describe a road that goes upwards and downwards, as in the image below?

[image: photo]

I'm not quite sure what word to use, although I am sure that there is one. Is it a zig-zag road?

By the way, the photo is from the Roller Coaster Highway in Oklahoma.

---

(There was a proposed duplicate,  "[Does calling a road 'wavy' convey its shape clearly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450717/does-calling-a-road-wavy-convey-its-shape-clearly)", but that question is about a road that goes left and right- this one is about a road going up and down.)

Comment: Do you know where this picture is taken?

Comment: @Agangu: it's **Roller Coaster Highway In Tulsa, Oklahoma**.

Comment: I think your picture says hilly road under it. See my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does calling a road 'wavy' convey its shape clearly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450717/does-calling-a-road-wavy-convey-its-shape-clearly)

Comment: @computercarguy Not a dupe. The road in the other question appears to be flat yet winding. The road in this question is neither flat nor winding.

Comment: @computercarguy like laurel said, that question is significantly different. I wouldn't even call it related.

Comment: Rolling terrain. https://connect.ncdot.gov/projects/Roadway/Lists/Roadway-Design-Manual/DispForm.aspx?ID=16&ContentTypeId=0x01000AB0E7EB8C061D47AA9DC7DDD0827991

Comment: The correct adjective is "Norwegian"...

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

"Undulate" is often used for roads that go up and down, while 'zig-zag' is used for roads that repeatedly bend to the left and right.

> The road undulates for three miles before descending into a valley.

> I enjoy an undulating road while driving, but not while cycling.

Comment: As of this comment, this is the only example I see that I might actually use in writing!

Comment: That would be a good word for describing it in a book or similar form of writing, but in casual conversation that would sound out of place to me.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=VfzJW_CPLubQrgTepqjIBw&q=%22undulating+road%22&oq=%22undulating+road%22&gs_l=img.3..0i30k1j0i24k1.1683.3793.0.4056.2.2.0.0.0.0.141.278.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.2.277...0.0.uzqE8MtUJeo

Comment: A hilly road in everyday parlance.

Comment: I'll admit. If I saw undulate before this answer, I'd have to look it up to figure out what it means.

Comment: @Herohtar agreed. It would make for a good metaphor, but undulating means that something is physically moving up and down. Roads generally don't undulate unless something like this is going on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9gTGPj216s

Comment: It's kind of ironic that we don't like "wavy", but we do like "undulating" - even though "undulating" comes from Latin "unda", which means "a wave". Language isn't logical!

Comment: Roads do not do many things physically that we still say they do. Roads do not wind, for example.

Comment: @JustinLardinois that's one of multiple definitions for undulate. Another is "have a smoothly rising and falling form or outline" which has no mention of motion.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen "undulate" to mean more general oscillatory motion, rather than exclusively referring to up-and-down.  But this may be one of those points of "proper usage" that is not always adhered to.

Comment: Undulate does not mean vertically rising and falling. An undulating road could just as easily refer to a road that swerves left to right, just as a snake's locomotion is described as undulating. This answer isn't wrong, but it is not common usage and is not what most people I know would think of when describing the road shown in the picture.

Comment: @barbecue "Undulate" was the answer I immediately thought of when I saw the question title.  (60-yo BrE native)

Comment: @MartinBonner Fair enough, I'm from the southern US, and hilly is what people here say. Undulate can however mean winding or zig-zagging. It's used to describe the movements of snakes, tentacles, etc.

Comment: "Undulating" was the first word I thought of upon reading the question too @MartinBonner , BrE native

Answer (score 70):

I would go with

> [**Hilly**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87014?redirectedFrom=hilly#eid)
>
> 1. Characterized by hills; abounding in hills.

As in, "Are you sure we should take that road? Won't it be very hilly?"

Comment: This is the term I would use to describe it, and the one I usually hear.

Comment: This is too generic and doesn't describe the situation in the photograph very well at all.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Why not? I think it does. This is what most people would say.

Comment: @only_pro "Hilly" just means characterized by hills. Any kind of hills at all. The road in question certainly has hills but "hilly" does nothing to suggest this repeated sequence of short up-and-down hills. It's like seeing somebody in a tuxedo and saying "They're wearing clothes": it's undeniably true but it doesn't convey any of the unusualness of the situation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby please note that "Hilly" also means "abounding in hills," which this road absolutely appears to be.

Comment: @scohe001 "Abounding in hills" has no significantly different meaning from "characterized by hills". "Hilly" is just saying "This road has hills". It's true but it's not going to make the reader think of the formation shown in the photograph.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "abounding" by definition means that there are a great number of hills: "*To be plentiful; to exist or be present in large numbers or in great quantity; to prevail widely;...*" but you've made your point and I don't think I can convince you otherwise.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Agreed. I'd still call this a hilly road, and I think most other people would too.

Comment: @only_pro I think most people would even agree that it's just "a road". This doesn't mean that "a road" is a good description of this particular road. Anyway, I'm done bashing my head against the wall on this point.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ok. I think most people would agree that hilly is a good description of this road. Do you have a better suggestion, or do you just want to complain about this answer? Feel free to downvote or write your own answer, but I don't understand why you're commenting.

Comment: @only_pro If you downvote without commenting, people complain that you should explain yourself. If you downvote and comment, people complain that you should just downvote and move on. Basically, you can't win.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think that's more of a site-specific thing. I know on IPS at least, commenting just to explain why you downvoted and disagree with an answer is strongly discouraged (meta post [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2499/11811)). I'm not on ELU often enough to know their policy on the matter.

Answer (score 40):

Rolling ([OXD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rolling))

> (of land) extending in gentle undulations.
>   *‘the rolling countryside’*

Alternatively, roller-coaster ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roller-coaster))

> marked by numerous ups and downs
>   *an entertainer's roller-coaster career*

Comment: I would immediately think of something like the picture that the OP posted if I was told it was a "rolling road"

Comment: I would have guessed a "rolling road" was some kind of sliproad for vehicles with non-functional breaks to roll to a halt on.

Comment: Another use of rolling road is those car power and brake testers ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a no-go. Rolling countryside but not rolling road.

Comment: No.  'Rolling road' has another quite specific meaning.

Comment: @Lambie, and yet, 'rolling road' was my first thought after reading only the title, and then after seeing the image hoping to add it as an answer. I am aware of what a rolling road is in the context of motor vehicles also.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 No, that's an escape lane.

Comment: @LaurencePayne Words and phrases can have more than one meaning.

Comment: Some meanings also have more than one word, or colloquial names. Though I don't disagree, Rolling Road is likely not used in my suggested context.

Comment: +1 for the roller-coaster reference.  Any native English speaker should immediately understand the meaning.

Comment: @MontyHarder thank you! As it turns out, the road in the picture is literally called *Rollercoaster Highway*

Answer (score 12):

> [**Humpy**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89443?rskey=DOl7Bi&result=3)
>
> a. Having or characterized by humps; marked by protuberances; humped; hump-like.

One of the examples given in OED is:

> 1888   Co-operative News 4 Aug. 783   As the cars ascend and descend the **humpy** road.

(emphasis mine)

Also, the top result on a [Google image search for "humpy road"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22humpy%20road%22&tbm=isch) returns:

[image]

([source](https://drmrenfrew.wordpress.com/humpy-road/))

Comment: A kid might say humpy but a newspaper would say hilly.

Comment: Due to [other popular colloquial usage](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hump), words involving "hump" are pretty much not useful or appropriate for anything else...

Comment: @R.. Agreed. I feel like in most conversations using this word would just make the whole thing awkward

Comment: Speed bumps in the UK are often called speed humps. "Humpy" isn't a word that tends to get used for roads (note that the OED's example is 130 years old) but, if it was, I'd expect speed humps, not rolling terrain.

Comment: "Speed humps" also appears on signs in many localities in the US, but it's an 100% sure sign that some dude in local government just enjoys being a pervert.

Comment: @R.. the verb _"hump"_, as in slang for engaging in sexual activity, and the adjective _"humpy"_, as in something that is like a hump, are two entirely different words. You seem to be unreasonably fixated on the former. I find it disturbing and mildly insulting that you assume ("100%") that a person who uses the word "hump" as an adjective is a _pervert_ (_"A person whose sexual behaviour or inclinations are regarded as abnormal and unacceptable."_ ([source](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/141683))).

Comment: @oliver-clare: The comments here are not really a place for this discussion. My above comment with 100% and the responses should probably be moved to chat.

Answer (score 6):

***[Up-and-down](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/up--and--down)*** road:

> having an uneven surface:
>
> - up-and-down countryside. (Dictionary.com)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=up%20and%20down%20road&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cup%20and%20down%20road%3B%2Cc0) up-and-down road:

> [1](https://books.google.it/books?id=qhgIKMHie3kC&pg=PA130&dq=%22up%20and%20down%20road%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-ytSss5LeAhXDzIUKHZDHAOwQ6AEIOjAE#v=onepage&q=%22up%20and%20down%20road%22&f=false))  It is a curvy, up-and-down road.
>
> [2](https://books.google.it/books?id=yIKnQlk0viwC&q=%22up%20and%20down%20road%22&dq=%22up%20and%20down%20road%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-ytSss5LeAhXDzIUKHZDHAOwQ6AEIRDAG)) Now cross over into Israel proper and continue another 10 km to Nazareth on the up-and-down road.
>
> [3](https://books.google.it/books?id=wkRbAAAAMAAJ&q=%22up%20and%20down%20road%22&dq=%22up%20and%20down%20road%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit4cXFtJLeAhVJgxoKHThADbU4ChDoAQgrMAI)) 'I'd even like to be on that drowned rat of a bus going north along an up-and- down road,' I said,

Also “[wavy](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wavy)” is an adjective you may use:

> Marked by or moving in a wavelike form or motion.
>
> [Wavy road in Chongqing - CCTV News …](https://www.google.it/search?q=wavy%20road&rlz=1CDGOYI_enIT763IT763&oq=wavy%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i59l3j69i60j69i57j69i60.4750j0j4&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=x72pEsH44XhPLM:)

Comment: The surface may be very even in fact.

Answer (score 6):

**Camelback** can be used for this type of road

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/camelback

"Before the end you will be taken on a wild ride with a 540-degree helix, one spiral, a camelback hill and a carousel curve.
— Julia Fawal, Woman's Day, "10 Things You Never Knew About Roller Coasters," 24 July 2015"

Comment: #werh your quote appears to be describing an actual roller coaster, rather than a road that is like a roller coaster. Do you have one that uses 'camelback' applied to a road?

Answer (score 4):

In Britain, we have road signs for such roads and are flagged by "Hidden dip" signs:

[image: Hidden dip sign]

So you could say:

> the road has a series of [hidden] dips

but this isn't the one word answer that you were looking for, so I would have to suggest a variant of [Trevor's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469106/how-do-you-describe-a-road-that-is-up-and-down/469113#469113) and say *undulatory*, as an adjective, even though this is normally used as [undulatory locomotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undulatory_locomotion).

Or... *switchback*?

Comment: Not *switchback*. That is a road that zig zags up a steep hillside.

Comment: @Jim Interestingly enough the word switchback has more than one road-related meaning (first and third under transportation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switchback))

Comment: @James - Yes it was a roller coaster that I had in mind when I suggested *switchback*, in particular the humps of a roller coaster.

Comment: @James -  Regardless.  If you use that meaning you will be misunderstood.

Comment: A dippy road, then?

Comment: @KeithMcClary No. "Dippy" means foolish.

Answer (score 2):

When cycling we'd call an undulating section like that "lumpy" ([example event](https://www.britishcycling.org.uk/events/details/170544/2018-Little-Lumpy))

Answer (score 2):

A ***rippling*** road, as Rambling Rose would reply.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a term that is used for a road such as this, because roads are long and winding and ever changing. Thus any term would fail to describe the road in whole.

When I was a kid we use to have a couple of slang terms for stretches of road like this. Roller coaster road, and we called the up and downs "Whoopy-dos".

Comment: There are former Roman roads still in use which are essentially straight and make no concessions for changing heights

Answer (score 0):

There is a track in south west Tasmania that crosses many of the spurs on the flank of Mt Picton, and as such it goes up and down many, many times. It is known as the Yo Yo Track, so a road can be said to *yo yo* or be a *yo yoing* road.

Answer (score -1):

"Up-and-Down", "Undulating", and "Hilly" are all good words to describe this type of hill. Words such as "zig-zag" and "serpentine" imply a horizontal waviness, while "wavy" itself is too vague and can imply any possibility. Depending on if you're looking for an adjective to describe the road itself or an adverb to describe the path the road takes also expands the variety of words available to you for your usage.

Answer (score -2):

A Sine might be a good word to represent this in a technological context.

Sinewaves are common when describing electrical currents or generated audio:
[image]

Comment: One might describe a road as sinusoidal, but you'd be in danger of losing your reader with the relatively obscure mathematical term. It also holds no connotation of hills, a road that curves back and forth laterally is also sinusoidal.

Comment: It would be a good term for a magazine like The New Yorker. It all depends on who the audience is.

Comment: A sine wave gets much steeper than an undulating road thus, so it's not even technically correct.

Comment: @gerrit Try sin( x/10 )

Comment: One might as well just stick with "wave" and drop the "sine".

Comment: @gerrit I agree that sine should be dropped, but sine waves aren't always steep. Just lower the amplitude and increase the wavelength and it'll be smoother. The regularity would be uncommon, but not unheard of. so this is absolutely technically correct, just odd.

Answer (score -3):

Undulated ,  sinusoidal

In Spanish  is. Ondulado , sinusoide. 
In Paraguayan  Spanish is a little weird! 
Is something like: full of ups and downs :“lleno de arribadas y bajeadas”

Comment: I'm sorry but the answer [**"undulate"**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/469113/44619) had already been supplied, and was accepted by the OP themself. Better luck next time!